# multiple condition on joined table

Tags: sql-server

I have one small database for exercise, please see below ER-Diagram

[image]

I want to write a query that List student last and first names and majors for students who had at least one high grade (>= 3.5) in at least one course offered in fall of 2012.

My code below:

```
select s.StdNo,s.StdFirstName,s.StdLastName,s.StdMajor,e.EnrGrade,o.OfferNo,o.OffYear
from Enrollment e
join Offering o on e.OfferNo=o.OfferNo
join Student s on s.StdNo=e.StdNo
where e.EnrGrade >=3.5 and o.OffYear="2010";
```

But I got an SQL Error

> [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name '2010'

I am confused about the error, value "2010" is NOT a column name, the Offyear is column. So why did this happen?

The basic query is not that hard, but I am stuck on （multiple）nested query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offyear is shown as a number, so you should compare against the number `2010`, not the text `"2010"`:
`[...] and Offyear = 2010`

Comment: Wow! Got the result by just removing the " ". Thank you!   By the way, anyway to solve the above question by writing a nested query ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish with the nested query if this answer already resolved your issue?

Comment: @user3250365 I just wondering an alternative way to solve the question :  List student last and first names and majors for students who had at least one high grade (>= 3.5) in at least one course offered in fall of 2012.

Comment: You can probably write in a nested query somehow, but I really don't see the need to, since it wouldn't make your query any faster or easier to read.  If you're having issues with multiple result rows for the same student, try `select distinct s.StdNo,s.StdFirstName,s.StdLastName,s.StdMajor from ...`.